# Python Regex expression for parsing HTML document

Tags: python, html, regex

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_by_revenue

I am trying to find the names of the companies in order of revenue. It's a bit challenging because the titles all have differently formatted tags. If anyone could come up with a solution I'd be very grateful.

An example of my problem:

I'd like to match "Wal-Mart Stores Inc." and then "Sinopec Group" and so forth in order.

```
<td><a href="/wiki/Wal-Mart_Stores,_Inc." title="Wal-Mart Stores, Inc."class="mw-redirect">Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.</a></td>
```

...further in the document...

```
<td style="background: #ffffcc;"><a href="/wiki/Sinopec_Group" title="Sinopec Group" class="mw-redirect">Sinopec Group</a></td>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first, you probably don't want a regex.  Second, it looks like they're all anchors with class `mw-redirect` ... Something like `BeautifulSoup` should be able to select items based on that...

Comment: I understand that I should be using `BeautifulSoup`, although I am required to use regex.

Comment: Why not use the raw data instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easily with `beautifulsoup`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

x = ['<td><a href="/wiki/Wal-Mart_Stores,_Inc." title="Wal-Mart Stores, Inc."class="mw-redirect">Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.</a></td>', '<td style="background: #ffffcc;"><a href="/wiki/Sinopec_Group" title="Sinopec Group" class="mw-redirect">Sinopec Group</a></td>']
tmp = [soup(y).find('td').find('a') for y in x]
lst = [x['title'].strip() for x in tmp if x.has_attr('title')]
print(lst)
```

If its a single string, then you can use

```
x = '''<td><a href="/wiki/Wal-Mart_Stores,_Inc." title="Wal-Mart Stores, Inc."class="mw-redirect">Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.</a></td> <td style="background: #ffffcc;"><a href="/wiki/Sinopec_Group" title="Sinopec Group" class="mw-redirect">Sinopec Group</a></td>'''
tmp = [y.find('a') for y in soup(x).find_all('td')]
lst = [x['title'].strip() for x in tmp if x.has_attr('title')]
print(lst)
```

If you still want to use regex, then

```
<td.*?<a.*? title\s*=\s*"([^"]+).*?</td>
```

**NOTE** :- Match in first capturing group

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uQ7iJ5/3)

Answer (score 0):

Group the content of the `title` attribute in `a` tags. It checks if it's the first table cell after the ranking.

```
regex = /th>\n<td.*?><a .* ?title="(.*?)".*>/
```

It's known to work *currently*. But it's a fairly brittle method.
Check the [Online Regex Tester](https://regex101.com/r/fM2gO0/1) for regex details information